# TLE for WILLITST (SPOJ)

Tags: java

I've written code in Java for the below question, and getting the correct answer on my machine. But when I submit it on SPOJ, it is giving TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) error.
Can someone please help me in correcting / improvising this?

**[Question]**: http://www.spoj.com/problems/WILLITST/

*Here is the code i tried:*

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class WILLITST {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BigInteger n=BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(br.readLine()));
        ArrayList<BigInteger> al=new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        BigInteger x=BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger y=BigInteger.valueOf(3); 
        while(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==1){
            al.add(n);
            if(n.mod(x) == BigInteger.ZERO)
                n=n.divide(x);
            else n=y.multiply(n).add(y);
            if(al.contains(n))
            {
                System.out.println("NIE");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("TAK");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the Collaz conjecture. Anyhow, don't use an array list but a set to vastly improve performance. Also doing modulo arithmetic on a big integer just to find out if it's even is inefficient, when a simple `and` will do. Anyhow the question itself is impossible to solve, because it's been proven to be undecidable.

Comment: Thank u so much :). As u said, i used Set, and also for checking "even number" i used "and" and got successfully submitted w/o 'TLE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Submitted below code successfully, w/o TLE:***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
class WILLITST_BigInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BigInteger n=BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(br.readLine()));
        Set<BigInteger> s=new HashSet<BigInteger>();
        BigInteger x=BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger y=BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        while(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==1){
            if(!s.add(n)){
                System.out.println("NIE");
                return;
            }
            if((n.and(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
                System.out.println("TAK");
                return;
            }
            if((n.and(BigInteger.ONE)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
                n=n.divide(x);
            else n=y.multiply(n).add(y);
        }
        System.out.println("TAK");
    }
}
```